# C# functions and optional parameters

Tags: c#

I know that in C# it is possible to define optional parameters. My question is directed at how flexible this is.

Let f be a function as below, with **a** mandatory and **b**, **c** optional :

```
class Test {
   public void f(int a, int b = 2, int c = 3) {
      //...
   }
}
```

Now, I know I can call the function in the following ways :

f(1) -> a equals 1, b equals 2, c equals 3

f(11,22) -> a equals 11, b equals 22, c equals 3

f(11,22,33) -> a equals 11, b equals 22, c equals 33

How do I do to not specify **b**, but **a** and **c** ?

Comment: I'm asking this because I need to wrap up some calls to Excel macros with .net 3.5. The annoying thing is that some of these macros have 30 or more params. In VBA, setting params selectively is easy, in C# I need to wrap those calls as I am forced to stuff unused values to Type.Missing

Comment: It is precisely because libraries like the Excel and Word interop libraries have those methods with 30+ params that we added optional parameters to C#. Note that we also added *named* arguments, and we added the ability to elide `ref` arguments on calls to legacy object models. (`ref` arguments may not be elided on regular C# library calls.) All three features are necessary to make calls to Excel and Word look nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
f(11, c: 33)
```

And take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix the parameter with the argument name:

```
f(1, c:3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
f(a: 5, c: 6);
```

Although, strictly speaking in my example, you don't have to qualify the a:

```
f(5, c: 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use named parameters:

```
f( a:100, c:300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to define the method with other parameters and call the original one with them using this syntax:

```
public void f(int a, int c = 3) => f(a, 2, c)
```

More comfortable usability if you call it, but gets fiddly to define if you have more than 2 optional parameters .